# Downloading the folder from remote server using Java

Tags: java, alfresco, apache-commons, passbook

I have a situation. 
I am using [JPasskit](https://github.com/bitzeche/jpasskit/blob/master/jpasskit/src/main/java/de/brendamour/jpasskit/signing/PKSigningUtil.java) to generate Apple Pass. The why this JPasskit works is as follows 
1) It takes the location of the image folder, either as URL or String as input.
2) If it is the URL then hostname and port are ignored and rest of the path the taken into account.
3) Then it copies the content of this folder (at the path it gets in step 1) to new temp folder 
4) Then it works off the temp folder and deletes the temp folder once the pass is generated.

The things work fine if the folder is locally situated. But we use Alfresco as our content management server and all the images are located on Alfresco. Thus I have to give the path as the URL **hostname:port/folder1/folder2/folder3** which the API decodes as **/folder1/folder2/folder3** and throws FileNotFoundException as it cannot find the path in its local directory structure.
So I need some suggestions as to how do I download the folder from Alfresco server (linux server) using java and create a temp folder as this api does. This will let me override the specific method call from JPasskit API which copies the folder content into a temp folder.

Any help or suggestions in regards is highly appreciated.

I have added the code below form the JPasskit api that I use for creating the pass. The first method **createSignedAndZippedPkPassArchive** takes URL as the attribute and strips off the **hostname:port** from the URL and passes the rest of the path as String to its overloaded version.
I was thinking of overloading this method to download the image folder from appropriate path on Alfresco and then proceed accordingly.

```
public static byte[] createSignedAndZippedPkPassArchive(final PKPass pass, final URL fileUrlOfTemplateDirectory,
        final PKSigningInformation signingInformation) throws Exception {
    String pathToTemplateDirectory = URLDecoder.decode(fileUrlOfTemplateDirectory.getFile(), "UTF-8");
    return createSignedAndZippedPkPassArchive(pass, pathToTemplateDirectory, signingInformation);
}

public static byte[] createSignedAndZippedPkPassArchive(final PKPass pass, final String pathToTemplateDirectory,
        final PKSigningInformation signingInformation) throws Exception {

    File tempPassDir = Files.createTempDir();
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(pathToTemplateDirectory), tempPassDir);

    ObjectMapper jsonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    jsonObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    jsonObjectMapper.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());

    createPassJSONFile(pass, tempPassDir, jsonObjectMapper);

    File manifestJSONFile = createManifestJSONFile(tempPassDir, jsonObjectMapper);

    signManifestFile(tempPassDir, manifestJSONFile, signingInformation);

    byte[] zippedPass = createZippedPassAndReturnAsByteArray(tempPassDir);

    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(tempPassDir);
    return zippedPass;
}
```

Thanks,
Damodar

Comment: I just added the code.

Comment: Connect via [CMIS](http://cmis.alfresco.com/), select the file you want, stream to disk, then pass to your API?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CMIS protocol, it is a standard and it is integrate in Alfresco, or you can develope a webscript witch provide a file following to parameters (nodRef, fileName, type...).

Answer (score 1):

There a Java api, add some JAR in your project and there are a method to connect to Alfresco and file

Answer (score 0):

That code is only designed to handle file:// URLs so passing it a hostname will just be ignored. You will need to copy the data off the remote server to use the code as-is, how you do that depends on how you connect to Alfresco.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your webscript to upload your file